# Multipole expansion of a scalar quantity which is a function of a unit vector in 3D

Tags: multipole-expansion, spherical-harmonics

I have a known scalar quantity $A(\mathbf{\hat{e}})$ which is a function of a unit vector in 3D
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{\hat{e}}=(e^1,e^2,e^3)=(\sin\theta\cos\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta). 
\end{equation}
On several places, I have seen a statement that $A$ can be expressed as (Einstein summation is used)
\begin{equation}
A(\mathbf{\hat{e}}) = B + B_i e^i + B_{jk} e^{j}e^{k} + B_{lmn} e^{l}e^{m}e^{n} + \ldots,
\end{equation}
which I guess might be called a *multipole expansion* of $A$ on a unit sphere. I want the B values to be constructed from the following known C values
\begin{eqnarray}  
C &=& \oint A(\mathbf{\hat{f}}) d\Omega(\mathbf{\hat{f}}),\\
C_{r} & = & \oint A(\mathbf{\hat{f}}) f_{r} d\Omega(\mathbf{\hat{f}}),\\
C_{st} & = & \oint A(\mathbf{\hat{f}}) f_{s}f_{t} d\Omega(\mathbf{\hat{f}}),\\
C_{uvw} & = & \oint A(\mathbf{\hat{f}}) f_{u}f_{v}f_{w} d\Omega(\mathbf{\hat{f}}),\\
\nonumber & \ldots &,
\end{eqnarray}
where the integration is always over the full solid angle or, equivalently, over all the possible unit vectors $\mathbf{\hat{f}}$ in 3D. How do I construct the B values from the C values?

Even I know the concrete form of quantity $A$, I haven't included it in the question because I have a few of these quantities and want to understand and be able to derive the general case before I apply it on the concrete quantities.

The source talking about the closest topic I found is C. Cambon, S. Kurien, R. Rubinstein, *Scalar and tensor spherical expansion of the velocity correlation in homogeneous anisotropic turbulence*, J. Turbulence **16**, 11 (2015) 1058. However, this source has no terms with odd-rank tensors, stops with the 4-rank tensor, and it does not go much into the details of the derivation.